# Difference between different effective masses

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, mass

I know that effective mass can be measured experimentally by various techniques like cyclotron resonance, ARPES, or specific heat measurement at low temperatures. I want to know what is the difference between these effective masses or are they all the same? How are these effective masses related to the Inertial effective mass tensor components ($\frac{1}{m_{i j}^{*}} \equiv \frac{1}{\hbar^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} E(\vec{k})}{\partial k_{i} \partial k_{j}}$), density of states effective mass, and conductivity effective mass?